# PHP and Apache - flush & ob_flush behaviour

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, buffer

I'm testing some behaviors of `ob_flush` in my Ubuntu laptop using Apache2, PHP5 and Firefox browser.

The following code prints numbers from 0-9 with a second pause.

Every time it echo a number - it should flush it back to the browser.

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024 . "<br>";

echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa") . "<br>";
echo memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024 . "<br>";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i . " - " . memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024 . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
sleep(1);
echo 'End ...<br />';
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
```

I ran the code simultaneously in 2 different Firefox windows and this was the output:

**First browser window:**

```
0.26750183105469
The time is 04:17:09pm
0.26776123046875
0 - 0.26792144775391
1 - 0.26787567138672
2 - 0.26787567138672
3 - 0.26787567138672
4 - 0.26787567138672
5 - 0.26787567138672
6 - 0.26787567138672
7 - 0.26787567138672
8 - 0.26787567138672
9 - 0.26787567138672
End ...
The time is 04:17:20pm
```

**Second browser window:**

```
0.26509094238281
The time is 04:17:11pm
0.26535034179688
0 - 0.26551055908203
1 - 0.26546478271484
2 - 0.26546478271484
3 - 0.26546478271484
4 - 0.26546478271484
5 - 0.26546478271484
6 - 0.26546478271484
7 - 0.26546478271484
8 - 0.26546478271484
9 - 0.26546478271484
End ...
The time is 04:17:22pm
```

You could see pretty clearly that the two requests were processed by Apache at the same time and that the memory usage was 0.26MB.

**All good, Everybody Happy :)**

I copied-pasted this code into a class's method, and suddenly Apache no longer process the requests simultaneously - but one after other.

**This is the new code:**

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024 . "<br>";
$task = new TestTask(null);
$task->start();
```

Again - I sent the request at the same time in 2 different Firefox windows:

**First browser window:**

```
0.26746368408203
The time is 04:20:34pm
2.3088989257812
0 - 2.3089752197266
1 - 2.3089294433594
2 - 2.3089294433594
3 - 2.3089294433594
4 - 2.3089294433594
5 - 2.3089294433594
6 - 2.3089294433594
7 - 2.3089294433594
8 - 2.3089294433594
9 - 2.3089294433594
End ...
The time is 04:20:45pm
```

**Second browser window:**

```
0.26506042480469
The time is 04:20:45pm
2.3051910400391
0 - 2.3052673339844
1 - 2.3052215576172
2 - 2.3052215576172
3 - 2.3052215576172
4 - 2.3052215576172
5 - 2.3052215576172
6 - 2.3052215576172
7 - 2.3052215576172
8 - 2.3052215576172
9 - 2.3052215576172
End ...
The time is 04:20:56pm
```

Here you can see that the it was processed one after another by Apache (taking a look at the time), and also - because I encapsulated the code inside a class - the memory usage flew high to 2.3MB.

I supposed it has to do something with the PHP memory limit (which is set the 128MB) or the amount of memory allowed to be allocated by Apache concurrent requests, or maybe something in the OS (Ubuntu)? limiting the amount of memory PHP framework could allocate?

I set my MaxClients of Apache to a ridiculously high number - to make sure it has nothing to do with it..

Any ideas where or what should I look for and re-set?

Comment: Just a hunch: Are you starting a PHP session in each request (either explicitly using [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) or inadvertently by enabling the [session.auto-start](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) INI setting) where you weren't in the earlier tests?

PHP's session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes so the second script will wait at the point the session is reopened until the first script terminates or calls [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: @Matt Raines - even so, how come it works in the first time and not in the second time?

Comment: no, I'm not starting sessions in my code

Comment: @Asaf Nevo Without seeing the code for TestTask it's impossible to tell. I've written a simple version encapsulating the code in a class method and it makes no discernable difference to the memory usage or the ability to run concurrently, so it must be something other than rewriting as a class that causes both behaviours. My assumption was a framework or something else that was starting sessions, but it seems like I'm barking up the wrong tree...